# What was the old linux game for programmers, simulating a life on a grid of pixels?

Tags: programming, games

I remember about 10 years ago in the official Linux repository there was a program, simulating a life of creatures on a grid of pixels (each occupying one pixel). The point of the "game" was in writing a code for the creatures, which could live and reproduce in this world (i.e. you edit the C++ source code and recompile the project to add a new creature). You could also decide a few parameters, e.g. how strong your creatures will be. However, all such "good" features came at a price of increased consumption of the creatures according to a predefined formula.

After compiling you could run it, and observe your creatures, which are pixels on a (mostly) green rectangle (most of the "world" was "occupied" by something like grass). Observe, how the creatures live and reproduce or become extinct.

Could anyone tell me, what could be the name of this "game"?

**P.S.** Most probably it was in RedHat repository

**P.P.S.** After some search I didn't find the original program. It seems, that the closest modern "relative" is [Avida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avida).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly related to U&L

Comment: @jasonwryan What is the correct topic/SO site for this question then?

Comment: There does not have to be a SO site for every question...

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking of "Conway's Game of Life"

See pattern/algos details at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

BTW: It's not just linux, it can be coded in many languages, for many platforms.

Comment: No, it was not. In the game I meant you had to create creatures by writing a C++ code of algorithms, describing how they behave.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [programming game](http://programminggames.org/) named [Core War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War) released in 1984 using [Redcode](http://vyznev.net/corewar/guide.html) language. Many [implementations](http://corewar.co.uk/mars/index.htm) exist(ed). The simulator used to referee Corewar battles is called MARS, the *Memory Array Redcode Simulator*. A well known simulator is `pmars`. The source for pmars can be found on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/corewar/). You may find the package such as [`pmars-sdl`](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/games-simulation/pmars-sdl?full_cat) on Gentoo for instance.

[image]

From the manpages:

```
NAME
       pmars - portable corewar system with ICWS'94 extensions

SYNOPSIS
       pmars [ option ...  ] file1 [ file(s) ]
DESCRIPTION
       pMARS  (portable  Memory  Array Redcode Simulator) is a corewar interpreter with
       multi-platform support.  pMARS currently runs  on  UNIX  systems,  PC/DOS,  VMS,
       Amiga  (AmigaDOS command line), and the Mac.  pMARS implements the ICWS'94 draft
       standard, but can also be used in ICWS'88  mode.  The  base  system  includes  a
       graphical  core display for UNIX (curses, X-windows), PC/linux (svgalib), PC/DOS
       and the Mac (see APPENDIX). A line-oriented debugger  is  included  to  help  in
       writing warriors for the ICWS'94 draft standard.

       pMARS  runs one or more warriors written in Redcode that are provided as file(s)
       on the command line.  Running a single warrior is supported for  debugging.  Two
       warriors  are pitted against each other for standard play, but up to 36 warriors
       can be named for "multi-warrior" core war. If the  warrior(s)  assemble  without
       error  they  are  loaded  into  the  core array and executed in round-robin mode
       starting with the first warrior.  Warrior 1 is loaded starting at core  position
       0,  warrior  2, 3, etc., at either a random or fixed position.  For fairness the
       starting order is rotated after each round.
```

Comment: The program I'm referring to was not a war simulator, but rather simulation of the world of animals. The map user sees was the world where creatures live (like a piece of land as seen from bird's eye). The code for the creatures was to be written in C++ and compiled by the user. Some example creatures were included already (I think, one of them were called "cow").

Comment: @fiktor I understand. Many of them are variations of either Conway's or Core war... and it seems quite a few match your description. I don't know for RH, but maybe take a look at this [listing](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/games/) and this [search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=game+life+programming&searchon=all) in Ubuntu packages?